# Google Authenticator on Apple devices, certain secrets are not valid

Tags: c#, ios, authentication

We've incorporated two factor authentication into one of our applications using Google Authenticator.  In QA, something really weird turned up.  While I managed to fix it, I'm not really sure *why* the fix works.

For our shared secret, we assigned a GUID to the user when they begin the TFA setup.  The GUID gets base-32 encoded, and put into the URL that is converted to a QR code and scanned by the user with their phone:

```
 otpauth://totp/myapp_user?secret=g5swmnddhbtggllbgi3dsljumi3tallbmuytgljtg5sdgnbxmy2dgyjwmy======
```

And all works well for all non-ios machines we have tried.  On ios alone, it throws a really peculiar error when trying to scan the barcode most of the time:

```
Invalid barcode

The barcode '[same as above]' is not a valid authentication token barcode.
```

It meets Google/RFC 4226's minimum secret requirement (128 bits), is properly Base32 encoded, etc...  Why does it fail?  The typical reason for this message is whitespace in the url -- but there is none.

If I add a small seed to the beginning of the guid everything works just fine:

```
otpauth://totp/myapp_user?secret=nfygq33omvzxky3lom3ggmzyha2tgnjnmu4gezbngqzdgyrnhbtdqzrnmeywimrwmjsgknzymi3a
```

Essentially it's the difference between:

```
 secret = enc.Encode32(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("iphonesucks" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));  // Works

 secret = enc.Encode(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())); // Fails

 newAuthUrl = string.Format("otpauth://totp/myapp_user?secret={0}", secret);
```

I've got two crazy theories on why this could possibly have worked:

1. The ios port requires more than 128 bits.  My commentary/seed is enough to bump it over that limit, whatever that happens to be... except that I actually gave it more than 128 bits since it was a guid-as-string.
2. After Base32 decoding, the ios app recognizes the secret string as a guid and does something else with it.

**I hate fixing a bug and not knowing why the fix worked.  Can anyone explain this?**  Additional conspiracy theories on this topic are also welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was having the same issue as above.  It turns out that Google Authenticator doesn't like = signs in the IPhone App, but doesn't complain in  Android.

In my case I increased the length of the string before encoding to base32 from 8 chars to 10 chars.  This removed the three === at the end of the string.  I found this online as to why = signs appear in base32 encoded strings:

[The pad character (=) does not have a binary representation in BASE32; it is inserted into the BASE32 text as a placeholder to maintain 40-bit alignment](http://www.garykessler.net/library/base64.html)

In your case above the same happened when you added the salt.  The second secret you pasted doesn't have ='s at the end.

Hope this help.

Comment: Saved my bacon today, I was going mad looking for the difference between my android and ios clients. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 5):

5 years later... We can only get Google Authenticator to accept secret keys that are **16 digits long**. Shorter and longer keys just fail with "Invalid barcode. The barcode ... is not a valid authentication token barcode." Lost a lot of time troubleshooting this, hope it helps.

Comment: This helped thanks. But I was able to use key length up to 18 before this error. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not only the key lenght that is important

Here is how a sample URI should look like:
otpauth://totp/Example:alice@google.com?secret=JBSWY3DPEHPK3PXP&issuer=Example

In your case, there is no "issuer" or "accountname" in the URI, both are [recommended](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format).

PS. just for your info , Google Authenticatior does not support very long keys as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the answer above, I couldn't figure out how to make the base32 thing work for me (I'm doing it in just PHP). I had codes that would work, and codes that didn't and they looks similarly random.

I was generating a secret based on the first 16 chars of an upshifted md5. Sometimes they would work, but mostly not.

After a very long time of testing, I figured out that any string with a 0 or a 1 in the string would fail. All others appear to be fine. Maybe I'm wrong (and feel free to test out your own hypothesis), but this works for me.

$secret['1'] = 'XVQ2UIGO75XRUKJO';  //works

$secret['1'] = 'XVQ4UIG07SXRUKJO';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'XVQ2UIG07SXRUKJO';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'XVQ2UIG07SXRUKJO';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOR';  //works

$secret['1'] = '1234567890123456';  //fails

$secret['1'] = '1A3B5C7D9E1F3G5H';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'AB1DE2GH3JK4MN5R';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'ABC1EFG2IJK3MNO4';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'ABCDEFG2IJK3MNO4';  //works

$secret['1'] = 'ABCD123456789012';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'ABCDE23456789012';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'ABCDEF3456789012';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'ABCDEFG456789012';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'ABCDEFGH56789012';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'ABCDEFGHIJBKCLMD';  //works

$secret['1'] = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';  //works

$secret['1'] = '1111111111111111';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'A1A1A1A1A1A1A1A1';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'AAA1AAA1AAA1AAAA';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'AAAAAAA1AAAAAAAA';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'AAAA1AAAAAAAAAAA';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'AAA1AAAAAAAAAAAA';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';  //still works

$secret['1'] = 'AAAAAAA5AAAAAAAA';  //works

$secret['1'] = 'AAAAAAA1AAAAAAAA';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5';  //works

$secret['1'] = 'A2A2A2A2A2A2A2A2';  //works

$secret['1'] = 'A0A2A2A2A2A2A2A2';  //fails

$secret['1'] = 'A3A2A2A2A2A2A2A2';  //works hypothesis any 1 or 0 will cause failure

$secret['1'] = 'XVQ2UIG17SXRUKJO';  //fails with 1

$secret['1'] = 'XVQ2UIG27SXRUKJO';  //works without 1

$secret['1'] = 'XVQ2UIG07SXRUKJO';  //fail with 0

$secret['1'] = 'XVQ2UIG37SXRUKJO';  //works with 3

$secret['1'] = 'XV02UIG37SXRUKJO';  //fail added a 0

Comment: 8 and 9 also don't work. All other values from 0-F work.

Answer (score -1):

I also have a problem with this.

This link is valid

```
otpauth://totp/xxx.yyy:usertest009%40xxx.yyy?secret=CC5FCZNWTKNTOVN6&period=30&digits=6&algorithm=SHA1&issuer=xxx.yyy
```

But with diff secret key will make it invalid

```
otpauth://totp/xxx.yyy:usertest009%40xxx.yyy?secret=PBUPKS3SLJAP9V2T&period=30&digits=6&algorithm=SHA1&issuer=xxx.yyy
```

**I found out the problems**
The secret key must be base32 string.
I am using NodeJS, so I use **speakeasy** to create secret String base32. It works now.