# TOTP QR code working on Android but not on iOS devices?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, qr-code, google-authenticator

I have implemented 2 factor authentication using TOTP with a QR code in Java, which works great on Android. However, I get a very weird error when I attempt to scan the QR code on any iOS device and I have not been able to find the reason for it so far.

It seems that the issue might be appearing as a result of poor encoding, which is not allowed on the iOS version of the Google Authenticator app but that is only a guess.

The error message I get is:

> the barcode is not a valid authentication token barcode

Here is the code

```
public String generateQRUrl() {


    String secret = "hXYmnYsVWoEAXjKuAZcj";
    String QR_PREFIX = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M%%7C0&cht=qr&chl=";

    try {
          return QR_PREFIX + URLEncoder.encode(
                     String.format("otpauth://totp/%s:%s?secret=%s&issuer=%s",
                    "Test X", "test@gmail.com", secret, "Issuer Y"),"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

I have tried a number of different combinations for the URLEncoder none of which have worked so far. In my opinion, the iOS app doesn't like special characters of some kind, as also suggested in this C# thread([click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173288/google-authenticator-on-apple-devices-certain-secrets-are-not-valid)) but does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with generated QR codes and the iOS Authenticator App from Google. Double-encoding solved it for me:

```
@Test
void useUriUtils() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String encodedString = UriUtils.encodeFragment("HELLO WORLD", "UTF-8");
    assertEquals("HELLO%20WORLD", encodedString);
    String doubleEncoded = UriUtils.encodeFragment(encodedString, "UTF-8");
    assertEquals("HELLO%2520WORLD", doubleEncoded);
}
```

or as a URL example instead of encoding the space in String `HELLO WORLD` to `HELLO%20WORLD` like in this URL:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/HELLO%20WORLD%3Aalexander.pietsch%40foo.com%3Fsecret%3DJFWMPPNUIPG7CAOL%26issuer%3DHELLO%20WORLD
```

double encode it to `HELLO%2520WORLD`:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/HELLO%2520WORLD%3Aalexander.pietsch%4040foo.com%3Fsecret%3DYLCDNEHV5MSIOI5A%26issuer%3DHELLO%2520WORLD
```

The last one will be accepted by the iOS Google Authenticator App.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems with QR codes in iOS when using Lao language in the issuer field. A few years back I also seem to remember getting problems with the way in which spaces were encoded.

My fix in both cases was to simplify the data - to use only numbers and letters in the issuer field.